# React Native - Sending text messages by phone

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

i use fire base service. after wake up the app i need to send text message to users number by use device messaging, i install react-native-S M S but just work when on app and need to push user send button, can help me to send text message in background, thanks